# Is it possible to defer a computed observable until certain UI elements become visible?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a computed observable in my model which looks like this:

```
   this.TrainingPlanTemplates = ko.computed(function ()
   {
      var workgroups = model.WorkgroupsImpacted();
      var areas = model.AreasImpacted();
      var plans = model.PrescribedPlan();

      $(plans).each(function (i, v)
      {
         // A bunch of stuff that really slows everything down
      });

      // ...
   }
```

I then have a UI template:

```
<table>
   <!-- ko foreach: TrainingPlanTemplates -->
   <tr> ... Various columns bound to TrainingPlanTemplates properties ... </tr>
   <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

The issue is, the HTML template above contains various custom binding handlers and potentially has a large amount of data.  Rendering this table is somewhat slow (like 5 seconds or so).  This UI uses the jQuery UI [tabs control](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/), so I don't even *show* the data when the page loads.  Most users will never even switch to that tab, meaning I'm usually wasting my time binding that data.

**Question:** Is there a way to defer the binding of a computed observable until I say so, for example, until a certain jQuery tab becomes active?

**Ideas:**

I got a few ideas from [this page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).  There does exist a *deferEvaluation* property, however this will only defer the property until something accesses it, which will happen immediately as a hidden HTML table is still bound to the data.

One idea would be to create a new *observable* property called *TrainingPlanTemplatesLoaded*, and set that to *true* when the tab becomes active.  Then, create a dependency between *TrainingPlanTemplates* and *TrainingPlanTemplatesLoaded* so that when *TrainingPlanTemplatesLoaded* changes, *TrainingPlanTemplates* actually loads in the real data.

Any other ideas on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: My suggestion would be an observable flag that guards the actual logic until you are ready, as you suggested at the end.  The computed would check this observable and then be re-evaluated when it changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just making another observable that you check before doing your computation:

```
// set to true when you want the computation to run
this.TrainingPlanTemplatesLoaded = ko.observable(false);
this.TrainingPlanTemplates = ko.computed(function ()
{
  if (this.TrainingPlanTemplatesLoaded()) {
      var workgroups = model.WorkgroupsImpacted();
      var areas = model.AreasImpacted();
      var plans = model.PrescribedPlan();

      $(plans).each(function (i, v)
      {
         // A bunch of stuff that really slows everything down
      });

      // ...
  }
}, this);
```

Comment: Yea, this seems to be the best way..  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure its possible, [see my example](http://jsfiddle.net/c7tcE/10/):

```
function VM(){
    var self = this;
    self.FirstName = ko.observable("John");
    self.LastName = ko.observable("Smith");
    self.canShow = ko.observable(false);
    self.FullName = ko.computed(function(){
        if (self.canShow()){
            return self.FirstName() + " " + self.LastName();
        }
    });
}
myVm = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(myVm);

// Represents that at some point
// Some function make something happen
setTimeout(function(){
    // Let's say we check if an element was visible
    // or check anything that we want to know has happened, then:
    myVm.canShow(true);
}, 4000);


<p data-bind="text: FirstName"></p>
<p data-bind="text: LastName"></p>
<p data-bind="text: FullName"></p>
```